# How to change button text the first tap and on the second tap

Tags: android, button

I have a set of buttons that I want to make xo game like.
I want to change button text the first click and then change it again in the second click.

I have made this method (assigned the method to my buttons already) :-

```
private String  calltext = "x";
private String  calltext1 = "o";

public void MyMethod(View v){

   final Button btn = (Button) v;
   final Button.OnClickListener mylistener = new Button.OnClickListener(){

   public void onClick(View v) {                    
      btn.setText(calltext);
   };           
}};

btn.setOnClickListener(mylistener);
```

Comment: do you mean you want to toggle the button text between `x` and `o`? If so, you can just put an `if` in your `onClick` method to check what the current value of the button text is, and then change it to the other one.

Comment: yes i meant toggle x and o how cam i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String currentText = btn.getText().toString();
    btn.setText(currentText.equals("x") ? "o" : "x");
}
```

With this code, each time the button is clicked its text will switch between "x" and "o".

Comment: thanks for your reply , i wanted to ask why the method runs only on my second click on the buttons ?how to make it run on first click?

Comment: Try to add `btn.setText("x")` in `onCreate()`, this may help.